# Reconstructing the climatology of a station using reanalysis

Tags: meteorology, climatology

We have lots of data measured by weather stations in our network, but unfortunately their temporal coverage is not sufficient to compute a full 30 years climatology (e.g. over the 1991-2020 period). However, we still want to compute some reference for the station which will allow us to get an idea on how warmer/colder or drier/wetter a certain period (week, month, season, year...) was.

I came up with a cool trick, that I believe someone else in the literature used, although I could not find evidence anywhere. Using reanalysis (`ERA5-Land`) data on a period where I have coverage from both model and station data I can attempt to build a relationship that links the two: can be something simple from a linear regression to something more complicated like find a SVM model that fits the closest grid points values from the reanalysis to the station data.

Once this "model" is found, I can use it on the reanalysis data of the period 1991-2020 to get, as output, a "fictitious" climatology for the station. This works pretty well for temperature, as it has a clear seasonal cycle and no distinct day-to-day variability, but fails completely to capture the precipitation sudden changes, maybe also due to the fact that reanalysis are hardly capturing local precipitation features.

[image]

Does anyone have useful resources/ideas that could help me in improving the model?